# Show comments related to a post within a while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a while loop which lists user posts from my database.
I also want to show comments that have been made on that post.

The comments referece the session id so I can compare those, another while loop within the while loop which does a query something like the one below is what springs to mind but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT comments.comment, comments.sender WHERE comments.item = '$post_id'
```

is there a better way to do this where I can just echo the 'comments.sender' and comments.comment within the the below while loop.

```
<?php 
    // my query goes here and shows a series of posts
    $news = mysql_query($qry);

    while($newsPost = mysql_fetch_array($news)){
    // show user comments here

    }
 ?>
```

Any help with this would be great, I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase this or what I might need to search for to get the best advise.

Comment: You might want to look into SQL `JOIN`'s

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "SELECT newsPosts.id,newsPosts.title,comments.comment, comments.sender,newsPosts.id FROM comments INNER JOIN newsPosts ON newsPosts.id = comments.item WHERE comments.item = '$post_id'";
 $news = mysql_query($sql);
 $newsid = '';
 while($newsPost = mysql_fetch_array($news)){
  if($newsid !=$newsPost['id']){
    echo $newsPost['title'].'<br>';
    $newsid = $newsPost['id'];
  }
  // show user comments here
   echo ''.$newsPost['comment'].' '.$newsPost['sender'].' <br>';
 }
```

Comment: sorry, you've mis-understood, newsPosts is a qry to show all news posts selected, so that while loop shows those and within that I also need a comments qry where comment_item = newpostId and do this for each news post.

Comment: then use join where id is primary key in newsPosts 
    $sql = "SELECT comments.comment, comments.sender,newsPosts.id FROM comments INNER JOIN newsPosts ON newsPosts.id = comments.item WHERE comments.item = '$post_id'";

Comment: I'll give this a try and see what results it chucks out. thanks

Comment: I actually still have the issue with how to show each message, the data isn't so much of a problem, its just how I show a list of comments where applicable within my while that shows a list of news posts

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use an ajax function to run a php page which echo's the result in html rows and on postback to the page I used the jQuery function .load to reload the panel